# p2p broadcasting - should be working?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, p2p

Just want to be sure I am broadcasting my p2p stream correctly. I cannot play the stream so I want to make sure I am broadcasting correctly first then I will move on to worrying about playing it.

I created a netconnection.
nc.connect("rtmfp://blah/multicast");
onNetStatus I check for connection success. On connection success get my webcam and audio and attach it to my stage for local viewing.

When I click Publish it makes a netgroup with the nc. On netgroup success I create a netstream with the nc. I attach the camera and audio to the netstream. On netstream success I publish. I get publish success.

Does that mean I am publishing correctly? I have no way of conveniently viewing the stream. When I try to make a new netconnection, netstream, and try play it doesn't work. I don't know if it is because it refuses to play my own stream or if I am not publishing correctly. It does say I am publishing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be good.

Check with Adobe's article [Create a simple P2P chat application](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Create_a_simple_P2P_chat_application-16563.html)

In short the process is like this:

1. netConnection = new NetConnection();
2. netConnection.connect
3. gs = new GroupSpecifier
4. netGroup = new NetGroup(netConnection, gs.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
5. netStream = new NetStream(netConnection, gs.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
6. netStream.publish